# Spark get all rows with same values in array in column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark Dataframe with columns `id` and `hashes`, where the column `hashes` contains a `Seq` of integer values of length `n`. Example:

```
+----+--------------------+
+  id|              hashes|
+----+--------------------+
|0   |     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|
|1   |     [1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|
|2   |     [9, 3, 6, 8, 0]|
+-------------------------+
```

I want to get a dataframe with all the rows for which the arrays in `hashes` match in at least one position. More formally, I want a dataframe with an additional column `matches` that for each row `r` contains a `Seq` of `id`s of rows where `hashes[r][i] == hashes[k][i]` with `k` being any other row for at leas one value of `i`.

For my example data, the result would be:

```
+---+---------------+-------+
|id |hashes         |matches|
+---+---------------+-------+
|0  |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|[1]    |
|1  |[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|[0]    |
|2  |[9, 3, 6, 8, 0]|[]     |
+---+---------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spark 3, the following code compares arrays between rows, keeping only rows where the two arrays share at least one element at the same position. `df` is your input dataframe:

```scala
    df.join(
      df.withColumnRenamed("id", "id2").withColumnRenamed("hashes", "hashes2"),
      exists(arrays_zip(col("hashes"), col("hashes2")), x => x("hashes") === x("hashes2"))
    )
      .groupBy("id")
      .agg(first(col("hashes")).as("hashes"), collect_list("id2").as("matched"))
      .withColumn("matched", filter(col("matched"), x => x.notEqual(col("id"))))
```

#### Detailed description

**First, we perform an auto cross join, filtered by your condition of at least one element in same position on the two hashes arrays.**

To build the condition, we zip the two hashes arrays, one from first dataframe, one for the second joined dataframe, that is just the first dataframe with columns renamed. By zipping, we get an array of `{"hashes":x, "hashes2":y}` and next we just need to check that in this array exists an element where `x = y`. The complete condition is written as follow:

```scala
exists(arrays_zip(col("hashes"), col("hashes2")), x => x("hashes") === x("hashes2"))
```

**Then, we will aggregate by column `id` to collect all `id2` of rows that were kept, meaning rows that matching your condition**

to keep the "hashes" column, as for two rows with the same "id" the column "hashes" are equals, we get the first occurrence of "hashes" for each "id". And we collect all the "id2" using [collect_list](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#collect_list):

```scala
.agg(first(col("hashes")).as("hashes"), collect_list("id2").as("matches"))
```

**And finally, we filter out from column "matches" the id of the current row**

```scala
.withColumn("matches", filter(col("matches"), x => x.notEqual(col("id"))))
```

if you need the "id" to be in order, you can add an `orderBy` clause:

```scala
.orderBy("id")
```

#### Run

With a dataframe `df` containing the following values:

```
+---+---------------+
|id |hashes         |
+---+---------------+
|0  |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|
|1  |[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|
|2  |[9, 3, 6, 8, 0]|
+---+---------------+
```

You get the following output:

```
+---+---------------+-------+
|id |hashes         |matches|
+---+---------------+-------+
|0  |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|[1]    |
|1  |[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|[0]    |
|2  |[9, 3, 6, 8, 0]|[]     |
+---+---------------+-------+
```

#### Limits

The join is a cartesian product, which is very expensive. Although the condition filters results, it can lead to an huge amount of calculation/shuffle on big datasets, and may have very poor performance.

If you use Spark whose version is before 3.0, you have to replace some [build-in spark functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html) by [user-defined functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-scalar.html)

Comment: Hi i'm new to spark and i'm using  <3.0 version, how would you go about replacing the exist function with a UDF