# get all rows with at least one same value in array column

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

i'm aware of the existence of this thread:
[Spark get all rows with same values in array in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64703719/spark-get-all-rows-with-same-values-in-array-in-column)
I've tried but i can't come up with a way of writing the accepted answer:

```
  df.join(
  df.withColumnRenamed("id", "id2").withColumnRenamed("hashes", "hashes2"),
  exists(arrays_zip(col("hashes"), col("hashes2")), x => x("hashes") === x("hashes2"))
)
  .groupBy("id")
  .agg(first(col("hashes")).as("hashes"), collect_list("id2").as("matched"))
  .withColumn("matched", filter(col("matched"), x => x.notEqual(col("id"))))
```

in **pyspark** using **Spark 2.4.7** where the function `pyspark.sql.functions.exists` doesn't exist.

the main difference with the request in the other thread is that **i do not need** the element in the array to be in the same position so given:

```
+---+-------------------------+
|id |hashes                   |
+---+-------------------------+
|0  |["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]|
|1  |["1", "5", "3", "7", "9"]|
|2  |["9", "7", "6", "8", "0"]|
+---+-------------------------+
```

the result would look like this:

```
+---+-------------------------+-----------+
|id |hashes                   |matches    |
+---+-------------------------+-----------+
|0  |["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]|["1"]      |
|1  |["1", "5", "3", "7", "9"]|["0","2"]  |
|2  |["9", "7", "6", "8", "0"]|["1"]      |
+---+-------------------------+-----------+
```

note that my array elements type is a string.

Could you help me with that? also is there another way to achieve what was asked in that thread maybe more efficently? thank you very much

Comment: could you explain the matches logic a bit more ? thank you

Comment: Sure, basically for id 0 we find the element "1" and "5" in the array of  id "1" but i don't have any match in the array of id "2", therefore since i have at least one match in id 1 i can write ["1"] in the match column of id 0.
This logic is applied to each row, iteratively. Hopes this makes it a little bit more clear

Comment: sorry, we find the element "1", "5" and "3" *, i'm blind.

Comment: Thats okay as long as we are just checking if an overlap exist and not the elements that overlaps. I have posted an answer for you. Let me know if that helps. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding you may need a crossjoin with `arrays_overlap` to check if the values from other ids overlaps the existing and then filter the rows which return true, then group:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

out = (df.crossJoin(df.select(F.col("id").alias("id1"),
                              F.col("hashes").alias("hashes1")))
      .where("id != id1")
      .withColumn("Match",F.arrays_overlap("hashes","hashes1")).filter("Match")
      .groupBy("id").agg(F.first("hashes").alias("hashes"),
               F.collect_list(F.col("id1").cast("String")).alias("Matches")))
```

---

```
out.show(truncate=False)

+---+---------------+-------+
|id |hashes         |Matches|
+---+---------------+-------+
|0  |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|[1]    |
|1  |[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|[0, 2] |
|2  |[9, 7, 6, 8, 0]|[1]    |
+---+---------------+-------+
```

---

Schema for the test output:

```
out.printSchema()

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- hashes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- Matches: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone is in older version and doesn't contain array over lap

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
from operator import add
#Creating Data Set
l = [["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],["1", "5", "3", "7", "9"],["9", "7", "6", "8", "0"],["9", "7", "5", "8", "0"]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(l)
df = df.withColumn('data',array(df.columns))
df = df.withColumn("id", df.id.cast("string"))
df = df.withColumn("array_id", array(df["id"]))
df.show(truncate=0)
+---------------+---+--------+
|data           |id |array_id|
+---------------+---+--------+
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|0  |[0]     |
|[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|1  |[1]     |
|[9, 7, 6, 8, 0]|2  |[2]     |
|[9, 7, 5, 8, 0]|3  |[3]     |
+---------------+---+--------+
#Explode the Data Set
df2 = df.withColumn("expdata", explode("data"))
df2.show(truncate=0)
21/07/21 12:14:52 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
+---------------+---+--------+-------+
|data           |id |array_id|expdata|
+---------------+---+--------+-------+
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|0  |[0]     |1      |
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|0  |[0]     |2      |
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|0  |[0]     |3      |
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|0  |[0]     |4      |
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|0  |[0]     |5      |
|[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|1  |[1]     |1      |
|[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|1  |[1]     |5      |
|[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|1  |[1]     |3      |
|[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|1  |[1]     |7      |
|[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|1  |[1]     |9      |
|[9, 7, 6, 8, 0]|2  |[2]     |9      |
|[9, 7, 6, 8, 0]|2  |[2]     |7      |
|[9, 7, 6, 8, 0]|2  |[2]     |6      |
|[9, 7, 6, 8, 0]|2  |[2]     |8      |
|[9, 7, 6, 8, 0]|2  |[2]     |0      |
|[9, 7, 5, 8, 0]|3  |[3]     |9      |
|[9, 7, 5, 8, 0]|3  |[3]     |7      |
|[9, 7, 5, 8, 0]|3  |[3]     |5      |
|[9, 7, 5, 8, 0]|3  |[3]     |8      |
|[9, 7, 5, 8, 0]|3  |[3]     |0      |
+---------------+---+--------+-------+
#Group based on the id to collect set
df3=df2.groupby("expdata").agg(F.collect_set("id").alias("set_val"))
df3.show(truncate=0)
+-------+---------+
|expdata|set_val  |
+-------+---------+
|1      |[1, 0]   |
|2      |[0]      |
|3      |[1, 0]   |
|4      |[0]      |
|5      |[3, 1, 0]|
|7      |[3, 1, 2]|
|9      |[3, 1, 2]|
|6      |[2]      |
|8      |[3, 2]   |
|0      |[3, 2]   |
+-------+---------+
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("explodedData")
df3.createOrReplaceTempView("calcdata")
#Join the dataset 
df4=spark.sql("select a.data,a.id,a.array_id,b.set_val,a.expdata from explodedData a inner join calcdata b on a.expdata=b.expdata")
df4.show(truncate=0)
+---------------+---+--------+---------+-------+
|data           |id |array_id|set_val  |expdata|
+---------------+---+--------+---------+-------+
|[9, 7, 6, 8, 0]|2  |[2]     |[3, 2]   |0      |
|[9, 7, 5, 8, 0]|3  |[3]     |[3, 2]   |0      |
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|0  |[0]     |[1, 0]   |1      |
|[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|1  |[1]     |[1, 0]   |1      |
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|0  |[0]     |[0]      |2      |
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|0  |[0]     |[1, 0]   |3      |
|[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|1  |[1]     |[1, 0]   |3      |
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|0  |[0]     |[0]      |4      |
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|0  |[0]     |[3, 1, 0]|5      |
|[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|1  |[1]     |[3, 1, 0]|5      |
|[9, 7, 5, 8, 0]|3  |[3]     |[3, 1, 0]|5      |
|[9, 7, 6, 8, 0]|2  |[2]     |[2]      |6      |
|[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|1  |[1]     |[3, 1, 2]|7      |
|[9, 7, 6, 8, 0]|2  |[2]     |[3, 1, 2]|7      |
|[9, 7, 5, 8, 0]|3  |[3]     |[3, 1, 2]|7      |
|[9, 7, 6, 8, 0]|2  |[2]     |[3, 2]   |8      |
|[9, 7, 5, 8, 0]|3  |[3]     |[3, 2]   |8      |
|[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|1  |[1]     |[3, 1, 2]|9      |
|[9, 7, 6, 8, 0]|2  |[2]     |[3, 1, 2]|9      |
|[9, 7, 5, 8, 0]|3  |[3]     |[3, 1, 2]|9      |
+---------------+---+--------+---------+-------+
#remove the id which exists 
differencer=udf(lambda x,y: list(set(x)-set(y)), ArrayType(StringType()))
df4=df4.withColumn('difference', differencer('set_val', 'array_id'))
#remove rows which is having empty array after removing the id 
df4 = df4.withColumn("size", F.size(F.col("difference"))).filter(F.col("size") >= 1)
df4.show(truncate=0)
+---------------+---+--------+---------+-------+----------+----+
|data           |id |array_id|set_val  |expdata|difference|size|
+---------------+---+--------+---------+-------+----------+----+
|[9, 7, 6, 8, 0]|2  |[2]     |[3, 2]   |0      |[3]       |1   |
|[9, 7, 5, 8, 0]|3  |[3]     |[3, 2]   |0      |[2]       |1   |
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|0  |[0]     |[1, 0]   |1      |[1]       |1   |
|[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|1  |[1]     |[1, 0]   |1      |[0]       |1   |
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|0  |[0]     |[1, 0]   |3      |[1]       |1   |
|[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|1  |[1]     |[1, 0]   |3      |[0]       |1   |
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|0  |[0]     |[3, 1, 0]|5      |[1, 3]    |2   |
|[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|1  |[1]     |[3, 1, 0]|5      |[0, 3]    |2   |
|[9, 7, 5, 8, 0]|3  |[3]     |[3, 1, 0]|5      |[1, 0]    |2   |
|[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|1  |[1]     |[3, 1, 2]|7      |[3, 2]    |2   |
|[9, 7, 6, 8, 0]|2  |[2]     |[3, 1, 2]|7      |[1, 3]    |2   |
|[9, 7, 5, 8, 0]|3  |[3]     |[3, 1, 2]|7      |[1, 2]    |2   |
|[9, 7, 6, 8, 0]|2  |[2]     |[3, 2]   |8      |[3]       |1   |
|[9, 7, 5, 8, 0]|3  |[3]     |[3, 2]   |8      |[2]       |1   |
|[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|1  |[1]     |[3, 1, 2]|9      |[3, 2]    |2   |
|[9, 7, 6, 8, 0]|2  |[2]     |[3, 1, 2]|9      |[1, 3]    |2   |
|[9, 7, 5, 8, 0]|3  |[3]     |[3, 1, 2]|9      |[1, 2]    |2   |
+---------------+---+--------+---------+-------+----------+----+

df4.createOrReplaceTempView("finaldata")
df4.show(truncate=0)
+---------------+---+--------+---------+-------+----------+----+
|data           |id |array_id|set_val  |expdata|difference|size|
+---------------+---+--------+---------+-------+----------+----+
|[9, 7, 6, 8, 0]|2  |[2]     |[3, 2]   |0      |[3]       |1   |
|[9, 7, 5, 8, 0]|3  |[3]     |[3, 2]   |0      |[2]       |1   |
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|0  |[0]     |[1, 0]   |1      |[1]       |1   |
|[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|1  |[1]     |[1, 0]   |1      |[0]       |1   |
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|0  |[0]     |[1, 0]   |3      |[1]       |1   |
|[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|1  |[1]     |[1, 0]   |3      |[0]       |1   |
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|0  |[0]     |[3, 1, 0]|5      |[1, 3]    |2   |
|[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|1  |[1]     |[3, 1, 0]|5      |[0, 3]    |2   |
|[9, 7, 5, 8, 0]|3  |[3]     |[3, 1, 0]|5      |[1, 0]    |2   |
|[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|1  |[1]     |[3, 1, 2]|7      |[3, 2]    |2   |
|[9, 7, 6, 8, 0]|2  |[2]     |[3, 1, 2]|7      |[1, 3]    |2   |
|[9, 7, 5, 8, 0]|3  |[3]     |[3, 1, 2]|7      |[1, 2]    |2   |
|[9, 7, 6, 8, 0]|2  |[2]     |[3, 2]   |8      |[3]       |1   |
|[9, 7, 5, 8, 0]|3  |[3]     |[3, 2]   |8      |[2]       |1   |
|[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|1  |[1]     |[3, 1, 2]|9      |[3, 2]    |2   |
|[9, 7, 6, 8, 0]|2  |[2]     |[3, 1, 2]|9      |[1, 3]    |2   |
|[9, 7, 5, 8, 0]|3  |[3]     |[3, 1, 2]|9      |[1, 2]    |2   |
+---------------+---+--------+---------+-------+----------+----+
#merge array of array
df5=spark.sql("select data,id,collect_set(difference) as dataset from finaldata group by data,id order by data")
df5=df5.rdd.map(lambda row: (row['data'],row['id'], reduce(add, row['dataset']))).toDF(['data', 'id','dataset'])
df5.show(truncate=0)
+---------------+---+---------------+
|data           |id |dataset        |
+---------------+---+---------------+
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|0  |[1, 3, 1]      |
|[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|1  |[3, 2, 0, 3, 0]|
|[9, 7, 5, 8, 0]|3  |[2, 1, 0, 1, 2]|
|[9, 7, 6, 8, 0]|2  |[1, 3, 3]      |
+---------------+---+---------------+
#remove duplciates on the array
remove_dupes_from_array = udf(lambda row: list(set(row)), ArrayType(StringType()))
df5 = df5.withColumn("dataset", remove_dupes_from_array("dataset"))
df5.show(truncate=0)
+---------------+---+---------+
|data           |id |dataset  |
+---------------+---+---------+
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|0  |[1, 3]   |
|[1, 5, 3, 7, 9]|1  |[0, 3, 2]|
|[9, 7, 5, 8, 0]|3  |[1, 0, 2]|
|[9, 7, 6, 8, 0]|2  |[1, 3]   |
+---------------+---+---------+
```